# jQuery change checkbox button text when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, checkbox

I have some jQuery checkbox buttons, and they work fine. However, I would like to change their text upon a click. for example: the button's text is "click me". when the user clicks it, i needs to change to "thanks for clicking", for example.

This is what I am trying using:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#button").button(); 
        $("#button").click(function(){
            if($("#label").is(':checked')) {
                $("#label span").text("Hide");
            }
            else {
                $("#label span").text("Show");
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
<input id='button' type='checkbox' />
<label id='label' for="button">Show/Hide</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your first problem:

```
       if($("#label").is(':checked')) {
```

`<label>` elements don't get "checked" only their checkboxes do.  Change it to:

```
if (this.checked) {
```

In the code above, `this` refers to the checkbox element that has been clicked, and we're looking to see if the `checked` property contains the value `true`.  It's much more efficient that `.is(':checked')`.

Also, the `<label>` element has no `<span>` child, it just has text, so

```
            $("#label span").text("Hide");
```

should be

```
            $("#label").text("Hide");
```

But you could shorten the whole thing using the ternary [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator):

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#label").text(this.checked ? "Hide" : "Show");
    }
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/qnrVp/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#label").text("Hide");
    } else {
        $("#label").text("Show");
    }
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLuVR/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     var th = $(this);
     if(th.is(':checked')) {
          $("label[for=" + th.attr('id') + "]").text("Hide");
     } else {
          $("label[for=" + th.attr('id') + "]").text("Show");
     }
});
```